# SVG favicon not working for Chrome shortcut

Tags: svg, browser, icons, favicon, shortcut-file

I'm using `<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.svg"  sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">` and it works like a charme for the icon in the browser tab:

[image]

However, when I create a Chrome shortcut (... > more tools > create shortcut), the icon does not work anymore all of a sudden and it just takes the first letter of the website as a fallback:

[image]

How can I make this SVG icon work for chrome shortcuts as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site is being hosted locally, I wouldn't expect it to show up in the bookmark,  If the site is being hosted elsewhere, though, my guess would be that changes are taking time to propagate, depending on the hosting provider or CDN.

Comment: It is online, but password protected currently. Could that be the reason? Or does Windows only support .ico files for the shortcut to be saved (in Windows Explorer)?

Comment: This hypothesis is very likely. The ico format is a windows thing, something it uses for the desktop icons. You can check this hypothesis by adding a .ico file. You don't even have to declare it, just make it available at the root of your website at /favicon.ico. This is a well-known convention.

Comment: OK, just saving the icon in the website root as favicon.ico did not work. But decaling the .ico instead of the svg actually did the trick. God is Windows slow with adapting new technologies...